# Can I store image from my app so that on tap, it will open in photos gallery?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have an image page in my app. I want to have it in my gallery folder. So that when I tap on image it will open from gallery view.

see the images below :
This is the page I have :

[image]

currently I am opening it in the app itself. like this :

[image]

But I want to open this image in gallery just like we open photo in photos like this :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you cannot open the app Photo from your application since Apple doesn't provide an url scheme for it.

You can find the url schemes available here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899

Comment: ow are you sure we can not do that?  :|

Comment: If you don't have an url scheme you cannot open external apps. If you try with private iOS frameworks or some hacks Apple will reject your app.

Comment: I found this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36450096/iosopen-the-photos-app-iphone-gallery-from-another-app
but not working for me :(

Comment: It is opening settings screen . meh!

Comment: I would pay attention to use these tricks since you risk a reject.